# how do i save multiple inputs to a txt file in python

Tags: python, variables, save

So I made multiple variables with questions to input. I figured out how to open the text file but how do I save all of my variables to my text file. It keep returning none in the text file

```
from distutils import text_file

kids = input("How many kids do you have?>")
food = input("Whats your favorite food?>")
tv = input("Whats your favorite sports team>")
work = input("Where do you work?>")
carmake = input("Whats the make of your car?>")
symbol = input("Pick a symbol !@#$%^&*()_+")

results = str(print(f"{kids}, {food}, {tv}, {work}, {carmake}, {symbol}".split(" ")))

file = open("passwordGenerator.txt", "w") 
file.write(results)
file.close
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd instantiate the different variables in a list and then concatenate the strings with a join (to make sure there's the comma and space between each word as in your original example).

To make sure that the file is handled cleanly, I'd suggest using a context manager to open and write to the file.

```
input_array = [
    input("How many kids do you have?>")
    ,input("Whats your favorite food?>")
    ,input("Whats your favorite sports team>")
    ,input("Where do you work?>")
    ,input("Whats the make of your car?>")
    ,input("Pick a symbol !@#$%^&*()_+")
]
results = ", ".join(input_array)

with open("password_generator.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(results)
```

Comment: this one works best. the other answers that were provided worked but all the answers was together with no space thus the reason why I was using the .split but when i put the split it returned an error. but this does what I want it to do thank you

Answer (score 0):

You want to concatenate different strings using `+`. And `print` is not required for this, nor is `split`.

```
kids = input("How many kids do you have?>")
food = input("Whats your favorite food?>")
tv = input("Whats your favorite sports team>")
work = input("Where do you work?>")
carmake = input("Whats the make of your car?>")
symbol = input("Pick a symbol !@#$%^&*()_+")

results = kids + food + tv + work + carmake + symbol

with open("password_generator.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(results)
```

Comment: @AboAmmar you forget the brackets on file.close

Comment: Yes, thanks. I changed to `with open()` to be in the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

The `result` variable is a `print` function, which returns `None` after executing.

Also, `from distutils import text_file` is a unused import. You can delete this line because it does nothing.

Code here:

```py
kids = input("How many kids do you have?>")
food = input("Whats your favorite food?>")
tv = input("Whats your favorite sports team>")
work = input("Where do you work?>")
carmake = input("Whats the make of your car?>")
symbol = input("Pick a symbol !@#$%^&*()_+")

results = kids + food + tv + work + carmake + symbol

print(results)

file = open("passwordGenerator.txt", "w") 
file.write(results)
file.close()
```